# Schedule a Restart for Google Chrome

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, reboot, scheduled

I am currently working on a project using Ubuntu 14.04 at an airport that allows passengers to view a map of the United States. The map shows a live feed of the flights (both incoming and outgoing). The map is showing in Chrome, as flash is required and Firefox is currently having issues with Flash. I have the computer scheduled to shutdown each night around midnight using gedit. However I need to find a way to have Chrome shutdown properly beforehand say 11:59? The problem is I can't find a proper script. Each morning the IT dept at the airport is met with a prompt on the screen say 'Chrome did not shut down properly'. Now they could remote into the machine and click to close the prompt but are wanting the process automated. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me, the command `killall /opt/google/chrome/chrome` closes Chrome properly.
To schedule the command to be run at specific time, you should use `cron`. There is a lot of instructions on Internet since it is an ancient thing. Or you may create a shutdown script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
killall /opt/google/chrome/chrome
sleep 5
shutdown -hP now
```

and use it for shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

After using the command, killall /opt/google/chrome/chrome in the task scheduler, I was able to program the time in! Tested and is working! Thanks!